# Is it possible to audit (or hide within) a Skype for Business meeting?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

My employer has recently switched to using Skype for Business.  Aside from a somewhat painful user experience on the Mac, its not so bad.  However, several of us have noticed that certain employees can join meetings without being listed amongst the attendees.  I don't mean anonymously- I mean the attendee count doesn't even register the additional bodies.

Is this some kind of audit feature that allows certain users the ability to secretly join a meeting?  Or perhaps its just a feature that allows someone to slip in late without disturbing the flow?  Or maybe just a bug?

I don't mean to sound paranoid but this activity only seems to occur for division heads, which is why several of us have taken notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is [yes](http://blog.greenl.ee/2013/02/07/conference-deactivation-ucma-trusted-participants/).

But "normal" people can't do it directly, as the only type of participant that can be hidden is a UCMA trusted application, using a trusted application endpoint.

For "normal" Skype clients to connect hidden, is to connect to a UCMA trusted application endpoint that does a B2BUA call into the conference.

You can see an example of this in Microsoft's [UCMA reference Call Center application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn454818.aspx).